# How to make DNS accessible to public

Tags: linux, dns, web, iana, icann

So I configured an authoritative name server after reading pages after pages of text regarding the standards of the server and its security. Question is how do I make my server accessible to the public such that they don't need to add my name server to their network configuration in order to access domains registered to that name server? I already have a domain name registered for that name server through a third party domain name provider.

Answer (score 0):

Your registrar will have a way to make your DNS server authoritative for your domain.  Look in their control panel for DNS options.  When you register your domain they will set the DNS servers to their own, which you can change  later.  When you set your DNS servers it will take a bit for it to update, so if it doesn't happen right away just wait an hour or so.  You should also flush and register DNS on the machine you are trying to access the site from.

FYI -  you got down voted because stackoverflow is for programming and not server config questions.